# speed of light and microwave in air

Tags: light, speed, microwave

I was thinking that speed of light and speed of microwave should be equal (since I think they are same! I am not expert on physics), but due to my calculations:

speed of microwave in the air coming like 150 thousand km per second,

and I know from school that speed of light in the air is just a little (maybe 130 km) less than c (speed of light in vacuum)

Can you explain it.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What calculations did you do to come up with the 150,000 km/s figure?

Comment: Calculate the speed of microwave in free space, then in air. EM waves always move at the speed of light in a vacuum, in a material they move slower.

Answer (score 4):

The index of refraction of materials does vary with frequency. The effect looks something like this:

[image]

However, for air the variations represented by this curve is tiny, generally much less than 1% variation around an index of 1.0.

The index of refraction of air for optical frequencies is around 1.0002, so the speed of light in air is about \$2.9985\times10^8\$ m/s, as compared to \$2.9979\times10^8\$ m/s in vacuum.

I haven't found a specific value for the index at microwave frequencies, but I did find the dielectric constant is 1.00 to two decimal places, which means the index can't be higher than 1.0025 (because \$n=\sqrt{\epsilon_R \mu_R}\$, but \$\mu_R\$ only varies in magnetic materials). [This](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.32.302) *Physical Review* article claims to have measured the dielectric constant of air at "radio frequencies" to be 1.0005893, giving an index of refraction of 1.00029, but the abstract does not say what frequency was measured.

I'm not sure where you got your figure for the speed of light in air for microwave frequencies, but for the propagation velocity to be 150,000 km/s, the index would have to be about 2, which is nowhere near correct.

Comment: Are you sure that the diagram shows the ratios between the speeds and not the phase shift? In the case of "ratios between speeds" a value of n<1 in ultraviolet range seems to be very unrealistic.

Comment: @MartinRosenau, you're right it must be the relative index compared to the high-frequency value, since index of refraction should never be less than 1.

Comment: Or I could be wrong, see [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71126/) Physics.SE question.

Comment: I would probably add how n is dependent on dielectric and magnetic permittivity which every medium has but nevertheless great answer

Comment: Can you please provide the source for that figure? I am interested in it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, microwaves are a type of light, so they will travel at about the same speed.  I say about the same speed because the speed is determined by the refractive index of the material, which varies with wavelength.  The speed of light in vacuum is 299,772,458 m/s.  Both visible light and microwaves will travel at this speed in a vacuum.  However, in air things will slow down a little bit.  Here is a plot of the refractive index of air for optical wavelengths: http://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=other&book=air&page=Ciddor .  At microwave wavelengths, it's pretty close to 1.00 as well, but I haven't been able to find any sources with a quick search that show any wavelength dependence at RF frequencies, or a more accurate figure without also plugging in numbers for temperature and humidity.  However, the slowdown in air is very small compared to vacuum, and it's very similar between microwave and visible light.  Other materials are another matter, though.  For water, there is a very significant difference between visible light and RF - at visible wavelengths it's around 1.33, while at RF it's more like 8.9.